Does the FFT in LTspice not work properly?
I wanted to do an FFT of a square signal in LTspice. Here is the simulation:


Here is the result of the FFT through R4:

There is no reason to have frequencies below 100 kHz according to theory. What is the problem?
Is it possible to get a better result?

What minimum time step and windowing method did you use?

The scale is in dB, the strange below 100kHz signals are 100 times lower, this is digital computation always has errors, the FFT window and sample rate counts a lot.

Modify Ton to be {0.5/100k-1n}.

Remove the dc value of your pulse. Center it around 0volts.

It does not really make the thing better  ....

Made with microcap v12
FFT is calculated on a "number" of points.
If you change this number, then it should be ok.
I make the test with using 1024 points ... and 1 048 576 points where it is "quasi" ok.


And if you make a little greater the rise and fall time (10 ns), then it is quasi "perfect" ...

if you make a little greater the rise and fall time (100 ns) ...

